# Jquery full screen mode rejected

Tags: jquery, api, fullscreen, kaltura

Hello, i'm try to automatic put on full screen video i'm using the full screen api ... this is the code

```
        function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
          if(element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
          } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
        }



        kWidget.addReadyCallback(function( playerId ){
           var kdp = document.getElementById( playerId );
           var theid = jQuery('.kaltura-player-wrapper').attr('id')
           setInterval(function(){
           var durationVideo = Math.round(kdp.evaluate('{duration}'));
           var currentTime = Math.round(kdp.evaluate('{video.player.currentTime}'));

        if (currentTime == 2){
            launchIntoFullscreen(document.getElementById(theid));
        console.log(theid);
        }
    
        // Whack fullscreen
        function exitFullscreen() {
         if(document.exitFullscreen) {
           document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
           document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
           document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
        }

        // Cancel fullscreen for browsers that support it!

        var durationFull = (durationVideo - 1);
           if (currentTime == durationFull){
               exitFullscreen();
           }

        if (currentTime == durationVideo){
             jQuery("#relatedredirect").modal({minWidth: 200});

                var count = 3;
                var countdown = setInterval(function(){
                jQuery("p.countdown").html("Il prossimo video tra "+count + " secondi");
                if (count == 0) {
                  clearInterval(countdown);
                  window.open('', "_self");
                }
                count--;
                }, 1000);
        }
```

error

    Request to switch to full screen mode rejected because Element.mozRequestFullScreen () was not called by an event handler quickly generated by the user.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Fullscreen requests need to be called from within an event handler or otherwise they will be denied.  from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode